# How can I collapse all #regions and methods in c#?

Tags: c#, ide

it is very annoying to collapse all one by one...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Like Steve said, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> plus <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for collapsing all regions *recursively*. This one is a toggle, meaning you can do it again to re-open them.

Do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> plus <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to collapse all regions non-recursively.

Source: http://weblogs.asp.net/mrdave/archive/2004/09/17/230732.aspx

Comment: Ctrl+M,Ctrl+O does collapse the comments and methods inside the regions as well, just nothing on a higher level (like the class or namespace itself). Not what I wanted.

Comment: what do you mean by recursive and non-recursive collapsing? do you mean nested regions will get collapsed if its recursive?

Answer (score 13):

> - `Collapsing and Openning` recursively: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
> - Just `Collapsing`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
> - Just `Openning`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

Quickest way will be to collapse to definitions via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. That will collapse all code down to the signature lines.

Comment: I like this one: CTRL+M, CTRL+L collapses a bit too much for my taste.

Answer (score 5):

right click -> Outlining -> Collapse To Definitions

Comment: Unfortunately, that collapses all of the methods and documentation headers too - not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

```
CTRL + M, CTRL + L
```

This will also collapse anything that is collapsible too, such as scopes defined by braces.