# How to collapse only and only regions in entire solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

[How do I expand or collapse all the regions in a project using Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894165/how-do-i-expand-or-collapse-all-the-regions-in-a-project-using-visual-studio-200)

[How can I collapse all #regions and methods in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569244/how-can-i-collapse-all-regions-and-methods-in-c)

Non of these works. I want to collapse **only and only** regions in **entire** project.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> : collapses single expansion.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> : collapses everything in single file.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> : disable collapse tool
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> : collapses documentations in single file.

Non of these are appealing to me. first I want collapsing to affect entire project. also I want to collapse only regions strictly defined by `#region` directive and nothing else.

---

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42852157/4767498

This answer solved the collapsing region problem, (thanks to @WaiHaLee for mentioning it). But I want this effect for entire project.

Comment: ok, how do I make it work for entire project? I have over 300 cs files in my project. I love simplicity, so every time I explore a cs file, I can always see minimal view. @WaiHaLee

Comment: The bottom line of the duplicate is: there is no such option in the IDE. You have to resort to extensions to do that stuff. There are tons of them, but I doubt any one does do what you need.

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks. one quick question. where does this collapse information lie? if I know where its stored maybe I can do it my self.

Comment: I think it is in the `.vs` folder, next to your solution. The format in there isn't really accessible as far as I know. You can write an extension to do so though. I guess that is easier.

Comment: @PatrickHofman great! deleting `.vs` folder and reset worked like a charm! exactly what I want. but it causes lots of extra work to do all the caching. I just have to find specific file related to this, to make required work minimal.